# SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mybatis, last-insert-id

Can somebody explain how works MySQL function LAST_INSERT_ID(). I'm trying to get id of last inserted row in database, but every time get 1.

I use mybatis.

Example query is :

```
<insert id="insertInto" parameterType="Something" timeout="0">
  INSERT INTO something (something) VALUES (#{something})
  <selectKey resultType="int">
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
  </selectKey>
</insert>
```

Code:

```
System.out.println("Id : " + id)
```

Output:

```
Id : 1
```

Comment: Is your id defined as `autoincrement` ?

Comment: It could also be a [The id is injected in the object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12106243/1504300) case like the one happened to me, aka "you didn't read well the docs".

Answer (score 10):

`LAST_INSERT_ID` returns the last value **implicitly** inserted into an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column in the current session.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, value INT NOT NULL);
```

To make the column autoincrement, you should omit it from the `INSERT` list:

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable (value)
VALUES  (1)
```

or provide it with a `NULL` value:

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable (id, value)
VALUES  (NULL, 1)
```

After that,

```
SELECT  LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

will return you the value `AUTO_INCREMENT` has inserted into the `id` column.

This will not work if:

1. You provide the explicit value for the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column
2. You call `LAST_INSERT_ID` in another session
3. You insert more than one row in the same statement (`LAST_INSERT_ID()` will return the value of the first row inserted, not the last one).

Comment: maybe mybatis creates two sessions, i will try to create a query to insert and select in one... thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

is per user and per connection.

You can read more in [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html).

Comment: @Silviu is it safe in connection pool? I saw someone said `last_insert_id` has problem in connection pool because same connection can be reuse in connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used MyBatis yet, but after you insert something into the table, check that the auto_increment value is being updated with the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT Auto_increment FROM (SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '<table-name>') as A;
```

Also make sure that you have no explicit value you're giving to the `auto_increment` field. You need to let the DB set it for itself.

Here are some other things you could try:

1. Make sure you read the result as an integer. [This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1543016.aspx/1) shows an analogous case that required explicit conversion to Int32.
2. If you're doing multiple inserts, know that only the ID of the first inserted tuple is treated as the `LAST_INSERT_ID`. According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) (Search for `use test`).

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions, after implements much complicated i find out about second one...
I will tell you second which is better one ...
It's pretty simple... just in query insert this `keyProperty="id"`
Like this : 
`<insert id="insertInto" parameterType="Something" keyProperty="id" timeout="0">
  INSERT INTO something (something) VALUES (#{something})
</insert>`
Query returns id of inserted row
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Example 1:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE prime2 LIKE prime;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); //From table prime!!!
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                3 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> INSERT INTO prime2 VALUES(1,1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                3 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec) //From table prime!!!
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a Table name to select the last insert id.

Example:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM my_table;
```

Comment: That would just call LAST_INSERT_ID() once for every row in my_table