# Generate next Id as per the max id in database using Java

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

I am working on a web application. It will have multiple users. I am using mysql as database.

In my application i am fetching the latest `id (from the database, using max(id))` , and then generating the next id for the new registration. This approach is incorrect, as the id might change between the time i update an id 
and i ask for the latest id. I googled up , and found `"last_insert_id()"`

But, i tried `"SELECT last_insert_id() FROM rdtype "`, but its gives the same number of 0 as the no of records.

How should i proceed?

Comment: it's just "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10294336/1066779) answer may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AUTO_INCREMENT attribute for id. MySQL will handle incrementing ID at each insert. The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows.

Check the MySQL reference at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using Hibernate for Database connection and works. There are 2 columns in my db, one is ID (generator type is increment, via hibernate), and the other is Registration id. I am getting the max id, then getting the registration id for that max id, then adding 1 to that registration id to get the new registration Id.... Moreover, i need to get this new registration id before saving it to the database.